# Class 'REST_Controller' not found in my Codeigniter code how to solve it.?

Tags: rest, codeigniter-3

I am New in REST API.i want to create a REST API With codeigniter.But i am face error thats i can't solve my self.

Controller:-

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
require APPPATH . '/libraries/Format.php';

class Api extends REST_Controller{

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('book_model');

}
```

//API -  Fetch All books
    function books_get(){

```
    $result = $this->book_model->getallbooks();
    if($result){
        $this->response($result, 200); 
    } 
    else{
        $this->response("No record found", 404);
    }
}
```

Model code:-

class Book_model extends CI_Model {

```
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }


 //API call - get all books record
public function getallbooks(){   
    $this->db->select('id, name, price, author, category, language, ISBN, publish_date');
    $this->db->from('tbl_books');
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
      return $query->result_array();

    }else{
      return 0;
    }
}
```

My Error While Test in Post Man:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Required files `REST_Controller.php` is present in a library folder?. if yes then check the permission of library folder.

Comment: @GopalBhuva i have already copy *REST_Controller.php* in my Library Folder.

Comment: Also, check in config.php file `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` to : `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'REST_'`;

Comment: Yes i am already change in config.php with $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'REST_';